# What is the "charge_refunded" dispute state for and how to trigger?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently using the PaymentIntent / Elements workflow.

The dispute object has a [status property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/object#dispute_object-status) and I do not understand what the [`charge_refunded` dispute status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/object#dispute_object-status) is for.

According to the documentation, the [`charge.disputed.closed` event](https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.dispute.closed) only has `lost`, `warning_closed` and `won` state.

From what I observed, if I refund a *warning (Request)* dispute, it get's `warning_closed` and I get a new Event `charge.refunded`. Otherwise (*no warning request*) it's not possible to refund, and it will change to `won` or `lost` depending on the outcome.

However, what is the [`charge_refunded` dispute status](https://stripe.com/docs/api/disputes/object#dispute_object-status) for, when the dispute status is `warning_closed` on a refund? How can I trigger this state in the Sandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `charge_refunded` status was deprecated by Stripe in a really old API version, [2014-11-20](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2014-11-20) where they said

> Updates disputes that are won to return the status won even if the charge was refunded. Previously, a dispute won that had a refunded charge would transition to charge_refunded.

This looks to be a documentation bug and that status should never happen anymore in production unless you use an API version older than this one (but really no one should!).